# I set my iPhone in Lost mode, but I receive today an Activation lock mail?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security

two thieves stole my iPhone 11 Pro and it's located in Vietnam now (it's offline now but as it's iOS 13, it sends me location). I already set my iPhone to Lost mode when it was still online, the thieve was able to send me phishing SMS using the phone number (I leave on the Lost mode screen). So I assume it's locked and it's safe from being unlocked.

But today a weird thing happens, I received an Apple mail (official) telling me someone tries the activation lock using the iCloud account. I'm confused because that means the Lost mode is no longer there? How they were able to go through the Lost mode to the activation lock screen? From the "Find me" screen on my Mac, I can still see this iPhone related to my iCloud account, and it's still in Lost mode.

And what should I do to protect this iPhone? I know I can no longer get it back, but I wonder if the thieve is able to unlock my iPhone?

Thanks.

P.S. I am sure that this email is genuine, it's sent from `noreply@email.apple.com`

Comment: Anybody can send you an email from `noreply@email.apple.com`. Did you view message source containing detailed info?

Comment: I don't think it's fake because 3 links inside this mail all point to apple official website

Comment: But yes I wonder how they could unblock the Lost mode without knowing my iCloud account, and if they did why this device is still under my account ?